# Laravel 5 - Limiting Eloquent Where Parameters When Using Request Object Data For Get

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have controller functions that look like:

```
public function get(Request $request){

    return json_encode($this->users->get($request->all));

}
```

where `$this->users` references a repository for my `User` model. Inside of this repository, I have a function that looks like:

```
public function get($request){

    return User::where($request)->get()->toArray();

}
```

I can dynamically pass in any number of parameters to search on through my HTTP request with the above code without having to explicitly state the column names.

This works well as long as all the parameters passed in through the request are valid column names.  It will error out if I pass in a parameter that is a not valid table column.

I have the `protected $fillable` array defined in each of my models corresponding to my repositories.

Is there anyway to enforce what can be passed into the `where()` method above so that only valid columns defined in the `$fillable` array in my model are ever passed in?

For example, let's say I have a `users` table with columns (`id`, `name`, `description`).  The GET URL I pass in looks like:

```
GET /user?name=mike&description=skinny&age=45
```

There are three parameters in the URL above, but only two of them are valid column names.  I would like the `age` parameter to be automatically taken out.  In my current code, the above URL will return an error response since the `age` column does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_only()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-array-only) helper:

```
return User::where(array_only($request, $this->fillable))->get()->toArray();
```

It will filter `$request` and will keep only key/value pairs which are in the `$fillable` array.

If this code is not in a model, change `$this->fillable` to appropriate variable or method call.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a package for doing this kind of filtering for models.  It will allow you to filter based on `User::filter($request->all())->get();` while defining each possible column's `where()` constraint.

https://github.com/Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
public function get(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();

    return User::where(
        $request->only($user->getFillable())
    )->get()->toArray();
}
```

By creating an instance of `User` you can then access it's `fillable` properties using `getFillable()`. By passing this list into `$request->only(...)` you can restrict the values you pull out to only those that are in your fillable array. Hopefully that should mean only fillable values are considered as part of your query.

Hope it helps.